# Headset stiff when the bike hasn't been ridden for a while

Tags: headset

The headset on my bike is stiff when it has not been ridden for a while, but becomes smooth again after a few turns. It does not feel loose. The headset is IS42 standard.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I'm guessing it has seals that get stiff.

Comment: Do you store the bike outside in the rain/cold/sun?  Or in a garage with wide ranges of temperature across the day/night ?

Comment: When was the last maintenance. The grease may have gone bad (gummy), depending on the quality

Comment: Bike is ridden in all weathers but kept inside. Has not been serviced for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it needs a service, which is pretty easy to do. There is likely to be some dirt built up in inside, perhaps as a result of some water ingress, or because the grease is old and gumming up.

It's likely that the movement warms the grease up, and lets it move freely. it will need a service sooner or later. This is something you can easily do yourself, and it's likely to benefit from a cleaning, and a smear of new grease.